# Sending and getting data via $.load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm writing a system in HTML5 and Javascript, using a webservice to get data in database.

I have just one page, the index.html, the other pages i load in a `<div>`

The thing is, i have one page to edit and add new users.

When a load this page for add new user, i do this:

```
$("#box-content").load("views/motorista_add.html");
```

But, i want send a parameter or something else, to tell to 'motorista_add.html' load data from webservice to edit an user. I've tried this:

```
$("#box-content").load("views/motorista_add.html?id=1");
```

And i try to get using this:

```
function getUrlVar(key) {
    var re = new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)' + key + '=(.*?)(?=&|$)', 'gi');
    var r = [], m;
    while ((m = re.exec(document.location.search)) != null)
        r.push(m[1]);
    return r;
}
```

But don't work.

Have i an way to do this without use PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Suppose your are loading the `motorista_add.html` in a page `index.html`. Then the JS code, the function `getUrlVar()`, will execute on the page `index.html`. So `document.location` that the function will get won't be `motorista_add.html` but `index.html`.

So Yes. To do the stuff you are intending, you need server side language, like PHP. Now, on the server side, you get the `id` parameter via `GET` variable and use it to build up your `motorista_add.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data this way:

```
$("#box-content").load("views/motorista_add.html", { id : 1 });
```

Note: The POST method is used if data is provided as an object (like the example above); otherwise, GET is assumed. More info: https://api.jquery.com/load/